# i want to use selenium RC without Testing Framework

Tags: java, selenium

I want to use selenium RC without TestCase, Junit or SeleneseTestCase.

I want to write a code which performs automation of my website. I don't want to use any Testing fromework link testCase or SeleneseTestCase.

I want just write a code and run my code without any testing Cases.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Selenium Webdriver API http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html. 
It does not force you to use JUnit or the like. It simply starts a browser and executes your commands. You can still access page contents and examine them if you like.

Comment: i used webdriver many times it have some problem. it could not detect dyanmic controls such as input boxes, iframe and other ajax html element which load dyamically.  waitfor method returns exception. is any solution for me?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Webdriver worked nicely for me, even with ajax. Most of the time I located page elements via xpath expressions.
IFrames are a problem of course, because they are not part of the DOM of the page selenium is accessing, best to get them seperately via their URL.
Maybe you should post your problems with "input boxes" and "waitfor" as seperate questions and see if they can't be solved easily.

Comment: my problem is that input box is in iframe element. and when url of iframe element is pasted in browser address bar , it shows blank tab. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

### Yes you can! :D

When I'm bored, I usually use Selenium to tweet on Twitter or post in Facebook. I'm still amaze in what Selenium can do. but in a way, we don't fully use the functionality of Selenium in doing so.

FYI you can do that in both Selenium RC and WebDriver :D